# Mathematica not recognizing n'[t] as dn/dt

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a simple problem. Normally in Mathematica, typing y'[x] is equivalent to writing "dy/dx" on pen and paper, right?

However, when I type n'[t], it refuses to recognize it as dn/dt... Instead of returning n'[t], it returns n[t].

Funnily, this problem is unique to n and t.... I don't have this problem for y and x. What's going on here??? I've attached a screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Something in your session is causing it. Use `Quit[]` to clear it.  Hard to comment without knowing the previous code.  Evidently `ClearAll` has not removed the problem.  Perhaps you can isolate the part of the code that is causing the problem by paring it back to the minimum to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Likely you have evaluated `n' = n` (or similar), which caused a new rule to be associated not with `n` but with `Derivative`. That could be why the `ClearAll` did not work.  `Derivative` is not safe to clear, so best just restart the kernel, a Chris said.

Comment: FWIW `Unset[n']` or `n'=.` fixes this.  Really simply quitting the kernel is a better approach when you see this kind of strangeness though.

Comment: @agentp The problem is that it's impossible to know what the definition was made for. `n'`?  `n'[x]`?  `??Derivative` doesn't help.  `Clear[Derivative]` will break stuff because in M11.2 now there are clearable builtin definitions (!)